# Forcing Custom Permalinks in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming, permalinks

Programmatically, without me overwriting the .htaccess file, what's the trick to tell WordPress to switch on custom permalinks (like %postname%) so that it creates the special .htaccess file that gives us pretty URLs? I need this for a special theme I'm coding.

**EDIT**: Note, this isn't a sysop or end user question. It's a question directed at WordPress programmers. Read the question below from @anubhava below and you'll see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the permalink structure via your functions.php theme file by doing the following

```
function change_permalinks() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->set_permalink_structure('/%category%/%postname%/');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
add_action('init', 'change_permalinks');
```

Comment: Note also that I did two extra changes. 1) You don't need to do this via add_action -- you can do it via plugin or theme activation code (which is under another WP action); 2) The above doesn't seem to create the .htaccess file unless you click the Permalinks page. So, I hacked it by making my options panel of my given plugin or theme load an IFRAME that loads this permalinks page hidden in the background.